# Flutter: setState not updating screen in Async function

Tags: flutter, async-await, setstate

From `initState()` I call `setDefaults()`, which builds a Person object, having done this execution should return to `initState` which calls `getPrefs()`, an async function.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();   
    setDefaults();
    getPrefs();
  }
```

getPrefs calls `SharedPreferences.instance()` and retrieves some data from prefs - hooyah!

This is compared with some fields of the Person object, finally `setState()` is called to update the screen with a Tile colour, and to render a Banner widget `if (usersTile == true)`.

This never happens, **`setState` never updates the screen**. I don't know why.

```
  Future<void> getPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> neighbourProfilesDownloaded = prefs!.getStringList("downloadedPersonProfiles") ?? [];
    neighbourProfilesDownloaded.add(widget._person!.firebaseId!);
    prefs!.setStringList("downloadedPersonProfiles", neighbourProfilesDownloaded);   

    usersTile = widget._person!.firebaseId == prefs!.getString("firebaseId") ?? "";
     setState(() {
      tileColor = usersTile ? Colors.grey.shade900 : Color(0xFF462c22);
      usersTile;
    });
  }
```

This question has been asked before. I've tried looking at other solutions on StackOverflow, so far as I can see I'm already following their proposed solutions, to await the asynchronous call then setState after it. And none of the proposed answer have been marked correct anyway.

I've tried assigning the value of usersTile inside setState, no difference.

The Tile colour does *sometimes* work, however not on screen load. If I scroll down the Tile list, swiping the usersTile out of the viewport, then swiping back up to return to it, I find that DOES update the Tile's colour and Banner. Indicating the Tile property assignments are working but `setState` is not.

This is not satisfactory, it screams buggy to the user.

I know this can work, because I have another class, another ListView screen in my app which seems to reliably update the screen on load. I've studied the control flow on that screen and can't see how it's different. Quite the boggle.

This is the Card Widget, with properties I want to adjust, from `build()`

```
return Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 4, 0, 4),
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
    color: tileColor,
    key: ValueKey(widget._person!.firebaseId! + "LoaningTileCard"),
    child: usersTile ? Banner(
        message: "YOURS",
        location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: CardContentWidget)
: CardContentWidget);
```

Comment: Please add the code where you used `tileColor` and `usersTile`, I mean build function.

Comment: I've added the ```Card Widget``` from ```build()```. It's not the entire build method, which includes things like ```CardContentWidget```, that's a sprawling bit of code. Thanks for your attention @alex-sunder-singh

Answer (score 0):

I think `CardContentWidget` uses `Card` in `build` method, `Card` has default background color as `Colors.white` by using `CardTheme.of(context)`.
You may have to reset with transparent or user Container instead.